# How can I tell if docker has frozen?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker comments like

```
docker-compose run -d import-external
```

can take a very long time to run.  The one just mentioned has displayed

```
latest: Pulling from osm2vectortiles/import-external
```

and there's no indication of whether it has frozen or is simply in the middle of a large download. Is there any way to get a progress indicator?

Comment: Usually it will give a progress indicator if it is downloading. Do you get any errors in your daemon log?

Comment: No progress indicators.  Perhaps because I'm using Windows?  That task did eventually finish... but the general q. remains.

Comment: You could avoid using the `-d` option.

Comment: Running on Windows yields an error message saying the `-d` is required.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way of starting would be to build the container first and then run the up/run commands. That way the image download happens first with a progress indicator and the up/run without the `-d` option will show the logs too. If you do need to use the `-d` option, you can use the `docker-compose logs -f` command to see the logs.